# How can I populate a table view based on a local json file?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm creating a simple game and want to create a level selection screen. As a way to save all the levels I created a JSON file. I am now attempting to populate a table view with the levels from JSON file.

```
[
    {
        "name": "animals",
        "levels": [
            {"start": "cat", "end": "bat"},
            {"start": "dog", "end": "pig"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "foods",
        "levels": [
            {"start": "grape", "end": "apple"}
        ]
    }
]
```

I've been able to successfully populate a table based on an array as shown below, but can't figure out how to do it from a json file.

```
import UIKit

var test = ["hello", "world"]

class PackTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return test.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = test[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

I would like to populate the table view with this JSON file to achieve a table that displays the names:

animals
food

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy:

Create two structs outside of the class

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let levels : [Level]
}

struct Level: Decodable {
    let start, end: String
}
```

and a data source array **inside** the class

```
var items = [Item]()
```

In `viewDidLoad` decode the JSON assuming the file in the bundle is named `items.json`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "items", withExtension: "json")!)
        items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

You can delete `numberOfSections` because the default is `1`, the other methods are

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].name
    // do something with items[indexPath.row].levels
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to populate the tableview with local json file , so here is the simple and easy answer you just have to check it out,

http://vasundharavision.com/blog/ios/how-to-parse-json-from-File-and-url-in-swift-4-2

i hope it works for you.

Comment: Sorry the code in the article is very bad and outdated. Do not use `NS...` classes in Swift if there is a native equivalent. Never use `mutableContainers` in Swift, it's pointless. Don't use `value(forKey` unless you can explain why KVC is explicitly needed. Do not use `NSURLConnection` at all, it's deprecated for many many years. Do not `try!`. Add proper error handling.